# Does one say "memoirs of" or "memoirs from" someone?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am having a hard time deciding whether I should say of or on in the following sentence:

*I will be utilising the memoirs of/from key figures.*

Is it correct that both would be useable but they mean something different:

1. "from" means key figures *own* memoirs. Those they wrote themselves.
2. "of" means that *someone else* wrote memoirs about the key figures.

Hope you can help me clearifing this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't write your own memoirs, that's a biography. *Memoirs of* means they wrote them. *Memoirs from* sounds like those famous people sent you the material.

Comment: Don't say _the memoirs_; just say _memoirs_. You don't want to specify a list here. Probably _of_ is better, since one can speak of someone's memoirs in the possessive, and that commutes with _of_. Same with _autobiography_

Comment: **Memoirs of a Geisha**, a famous movie, gets it right.